# 'module' object is not callable when working with Moviepy

Tags: python, class, module, moviepy

I'm working on a simple video editing program using Moviepy, but for some reason I'm getting a bunch of strange and, what seems to me, inconsistent errors.

The problem seems to be the "VideoFileClip" class, which for some reason can't be accessed. The code has run succesfully recently, but we're unsure whether some slight change has been made to the program or if there's an error somewhere in the library, which is causing the program to fail. We've tried 3 separate installations of Moviepy (Two separate installations and attempts of debugging using Anaconda on Windows and one using Ubuntu)

```html
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import moviepy



def clip(t_start,t_stop):
    myVideoFile = "C.mp4"
    myVid = VideoFileClip(myVideoFile)
    myVid = myVid.subclip(t_start,t_stop)
    return myVid


tfile = "timeStampLog.csv"
timestamps = np.array(pd.read_csv(tfile, header=None, sep=';'),dtype=float)
print(timestamps)


for n in range(np.size(timestamps[:,0])):
    my_clip = clip(timestamps[n,0],timestamps[n,1])
    my_clip.write_videofile("movie{0}.mp4".format(n)) # default codec: 'libx264', 24 fps
```

Error returned is here:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
my_clip = clip(timestamps[n,0],timestamps[n,1])
File "test.py", line 16, in clip
myVid = moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip(myVideoFile)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t really imported the things you need. Instead of just `import moviepy`, you need to do one of three things:

```
from moviepy.editor import *  # Quick and dirty
import moviepy.editor as mp  # You don’t need to specify everything you are using, just use mp before each eg clip = mp.VideoFileClip(params)
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip  # Mosy efficient but you need to specify everything from moviepy that you are using
```

For your snippet of code, I’d use the last one.

For further reading about how best to import things from moviepy, read the docs [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/efficient_moviepy.html#efficient).

Comment: Seemed to solve the problem thanks. I didn't know the syntax for importing well enough

Comment: @MagnusNyborgMadsen You're welcome! Please accept the answer so that future viewers know that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If any of the classes being instantiated are from the `moviepy` module you need to use their fully qualified names (i.e. `moviepy.VideoFileClip`).

Or you need to import the specific classes into your current module's namespace with `from moviepy import VideoFileClip`.

Comment: Seemed to solve the problem thanks. I didn't know the syntax for importing well enough